# how to pass js values to PHP without page refresh or on body onload

Tags: javascript, php

i have a JS script whose function is to return me the values of JS based on user hour, min, day, month, year. Now, i want to parse these values to PHP without page refresh. Actually that page is served as web services, whom we call using page url using GET and POST variables. My goal is to simple parse these client side values to server side PHP.
my JS Code:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var hours       = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes     = currentTime.getMinutes()
var day         = currentTime.getDate()
var month       = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var year        = currentTime.getFullYear()

var suffix = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
        suffix = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours == 0) {
        hours = 12;
    }

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    }
```

I want something like this:

```
<?php
echo $_POST["hours"];
echo $_POST["minutes"];
echo $_POST["day"];
echo $_POST["month"];
echo $_POST["year"];
?>
```

any possible solution or ticks or code would be appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: you can use ajax for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery's ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "your.php",
  data: { "hours": hours,
          "minutes": minutes,
          "day": day,
          "month": month,
          "year": year,
          "suffix": suffix
        }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    console.log( "Data sent to the server " + msg );
  });
```